# Bind to GeometryDrawing brush

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have 3 buttons in my user control, all 3 have little icons instead of text.

[Image buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EcyQ.png)

For example:

```
<controls:CheckButton Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ActionButtonStyle}">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource Video}" Stretch="None"/>
</controls:CheckButton>
```

The image has this code to allow me to bind its color later:

```
<DrawingImage.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V24 H25 V0 H0 Z">
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Control}}" Geometry="F0 M25,24z M0,0z M20.75,12C20.75,9.345,19.22,7.065,17,5.955L17,18.03C19.22,16.935,20.75,14.655,20.75,12L20.75,12z M0.5,7.5L0.5,16.5 6.5,16.5 14,24 14,0 6.5,7.5 0.5,7.5 0.5,7.5z" />
    </DrawingGroup>
</DrawingImage.Drawing>
```

In order to set the color I use this style:

```
<Style x:Key="ActionButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE22880"/>
</Style>
```

I can see the pinkish color when in design time, but when running the app, this is what I get:

[Black icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ymML.png)

*Some of the code is partial, but I've included everything important

Comment: The ancestor of the DrawingImage resource ("Video") is not the CheckButton, but the owner of the ResourceDictionary, e.g. the Window or UserControl.

Comment: So how does it work on the design time, and how can I make it work in run time as well?

Comment: There isn't any actual question in your post. If the question is "why it's not working", I'm just telling you why it won't work in runtime. No idea why it works in design time on your side, it doesn't do for me (in VS). For a working solution you would have to find an approach other than `RelativeSource FindAncestor`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to do that?

I basically want to have icon button with different color for every state (pressed, checked etc.)

Comment: I'd use the Geometry as resource and assign it to the Data property of a Path control.

Comment: Path data gets PathGeometry, which doesn't support the transparency of some of the path

Comment: Actually `Path.Data` accepts any Geometry (not only PathGeometry). And if transparency means unfilled regions, WPF geometries of course support that. I have tested your icon with a Path and it looks ok.